# Download a translation file in angular while ng build or ng serve

Tags: angular, download, angular-cli

I am using ngx-translate for doing internationalization for my angular hybrid application.

I have implemented it, but now I have a requirement, that I need to download the translation file from another URL, and this need to be done while building the application or serving the application (for local)

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add your folder structure to this post . Also mention , where the translation file is present.

Comment: The folder structure goes like this src--> assets--> i18n

Answer (score 0):

You would have a link from your other website going to:

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/assets/i18n/{lang}.json
```

Comment: I need to download and put it in the i18n folder while building the application